# onTouchEnd wrongly also works on disabled sliders

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I think I have a pretty simple problem, I have a slider with which a user can rate a picture. Whenever the slider is released (eg with onMouseUp or onTouchEnd), the value of the sliderrange is submitted. When the user already rated the picture, the slider is disabled and greyed out.
Problem now is that the "onTouchEnd" event is still submitted, even when the slider is disabled. OnMouseEnd doesnt do anything here which is what I want. How can I get the rangefield to not accept "onTouchEnd" when its disabled?

Here the code of the slider when its not disabled (coded in ruby on rails):

```
<%= f.range_field :score, class:"form-control-range slider", id:"formControlRange", onMouseUp:"submit(); displayRating(this)", onTouchEnd:"submit(), displayRating(this)" %>
```

Here the code of the slider when its disabled:

```
<%= f.range_field :score, class:"form-control-range slider", onMouseUp:"  submit(); displayRating(this) ", onTouchEnd:"submit(), displayRating(this)", :disabled => true  %>
```

Btw its not possible to just take out the events when the slider is disabled, because the user can also "reactivate" the slider with the click of a seperate button. Maybe its possible to insert the events with javascript but I dont know...
Thank you very much!